# Ubuntu Server on Asus F200CA no wifi adapter found

Tags: server, 22.04, asus

I just installed Ubuntu Server 22.04 on Asus F200CA and it can't detect Wifi adapter.
How can I resolve this issue?

Output from `ifconfig`:

```
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet X.X.X.X netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast Y.Y.Y.Y
        inet6 aaaa::aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 bbbb:bbbb:bbbb:bbbb:bbbb:bbbb:bbbb:bbbb prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 662  bytes 296202 (296.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 637  bytes 130377 (130.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 19

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 102  bytes 8346 (8.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 102  bytes 8346 (8.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Output from `rfkill`: (no output at all)

Output from `uname -a`:

```
Linux 5.15.0-91-generic #101-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 14 13:30:08 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output from `cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

Output from lsusb and lspci

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:5605 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0457:1028 Silicon Integrated Systems Corp. SiS HID Touch Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM70 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
```

It seems that it can't even find my wifi adapter, even if is on board. Some driver issues?
I tried to run this script from this post [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) but don't know quite well what to read from output (except there are no wifi card detected).